# Migrate Geonetwork to 3.8.1

Tags: metadata, geonetwork

I want to migrate to Geonetwork 3.8.1 since 3.6 then I have taken some measurements

BACKUP my DB PostgreSQL 
I change these files in order to point my new DB 
              C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geonetwork\WEB-INF\config-db\jdbc
                  C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\geonetwork\WEB-INF\config-node\srv

And finaly I replace the file metadata_data  by the older one in data directory

After doing these operations  the metadata records have been recovered. But when I try to display the full view mode it indicates that the metadata records are not found.

for the first full view mode i had this error

```
2019-10-11 09:54:26,841 ERROR [jeeves] - Error occurred within a transaction
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
    at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:176)
    at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:139)
    at de.fzi.dbs.xml.transform.CachingTransformerFactory.newTransformer(CachingTransformerFactory.java:120)
    at de.fzi.dbs.xml.transform.CachingTransformerFactory.newTransformer(CachingTransformerFactory.java:79)
    at org.fao.geonet.utils.Xml.transform(Xml.java:490)
    at org.fao.geonet.utils.Xml.transform(Xml.java:376)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.XsltFormatter.format(XsltFormatter.java:136)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.FormatterApi$FormatMetadata.call(FormatterApi.java:819)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.FormatterApi.getRecordFormattedBy(FormatterApi.java:330)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at ...
```

and for the second one is that :

```
2019-10-11 09:54:26,853 ERROR [jeeves] - Error occurred within a transaction
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.
    at net.sf.saxon.PreparedStylesheet.prepare(PreparedStylesheet.java:176)
    at net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:139)
    at de.fzi.dbs.xml.transform.CachingTransformerFactory.newTransformer(CachingTransformerFactory.java:120)
    at de.fzi.dbs.xml.transform.CachingTransformerFactory.newTransformer(CachingTransformerFactory.java:79)
    at org.fao.geonet.utils.Xml.transform(Xml.java:490)
    at org.fao.geonet.utils.Xml.transform(Xml.java:376)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.XsltFormatter.format(XsltFormatter.java:136)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.FormatterApi$FormatMetadata.call(FormatterApi.java:819)
    at org.fao.geonet.api.records.formatters.FormatterApi.getRecordFormattedBy(FormatterApi.java:330)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at ...
```

Comment: Try a reindex in Admin Console -> Tools -> Rebuild Index

Comment: already done with no results !! i note that the new records that i have added in geonetwork give the same error when i try te display the full wiew :                    An error occurred while loading a metadata view for the first option (full wiew1)     and the second one (full option 2])     : The record with identifier was not found or is not shared with you. Try to sign in if you've an account.     do you think that  i committed an error when i upgrade my geonetwork !! if you know the right way i can applied for test !!

Comment: Does the metadata show in basic view or is it not found either?

I'd suggest to attach the log produced at `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0/logs/catalina.out` or `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0/logs/geonetwork.log` when you switch to Full view.

Comment: It seems a problem with the metadata formatter. The log should show exactly what is the problem causing the problem compiling the XSLT.

Comment: What is the standard of the failing metadata?
I'm thinking that your schema plugins folder contents haven't been updated. If you go to _Admin console_ -> _Statistics and status_ -> _Information_ page what's the value of _Standard folder_ property? Is pointing to a folder inside the deployed WAR or is it inside the data folder? If it were in the data folder I'd suggest you to make a backup of it, remove the `schema_plugins` and copy the folder `webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/data/config/schema_plugins` to `$DATA_FOLDER/config` to upgrade the schema plugins.